# Create an pandas column if a string from a list matches from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which is similar to the follow but a lot bigger and complicated.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'weight': [70, 10, 65, 1], 'String1': ['Labrador is a dog',
'Abyssinian is a cat',
'German Shepard is a dog',
'pigeon is a bird']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Output

|  | Weight | String |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 70 | Labrador is a dog |
| 1 | 10 | Abyssinian is a cat |
| 2 | 65 | German Shepard is a dog |
| 3 | 1 | pigeon is a bird |

I want to create a new column, 'animal' based on column 'string1'

search_list = ['dog','cat']

if in 'search_list', then populate the value from the search list, else populate 'other'

|  | Weight | String | animal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 70 | Labrador is a dog | dog |
| 1 | 10 | Abyssinian is a cat | cat |
| 2 | 65 | German Shepard is a dog | dog |
| 3 | 1 | pigeon is a bird | other |

Please suggest how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it which leverages the built-in [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function and its `default` argument:

```py
In [7]: df["animal"] = df["String1"].map(lambda s: next((animal for animal in search_list if animal in s), "other"))
   ...:

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   weight                  String1 animal
0      70        Labrador is a dog    dog
1      10      Abyssinian is a cat    cat
2      65  German Shepard is a dog    dog
3       1         pigeon is a bird  other
```

Note that if `String1` is something like `"I have a dog and a cat"`, then this will return whichever animal appears first in the `search_list`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.extract()`+`fillna()`:

```
df['animal']=df['String1'].str.extract(pat='(dog|cat)',expand=False).fillna('other')
```

OR

If you have a list of long length then:

```
pat='('+'|'.join(search_list)+')'
df['animal']=df['String1'].str.extract(pat=pat,expand=False).fillna('other')
```

output of `df`:

```
    weight  String1                     animal
0   70      Labrador is a dog           dog
1   10      Abyssinian is a cat         cat
2   65      German Shepard is a dog     dog
3   1       pigeon is a bird            other
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df["animal"] = "other" # initial set
df.loc[df["String"].str.contains("dog", case=True), "animal"] = "dog"
df.loc[df["String"].str.contains("cat", case=True), "animal"] = "cat"
```

Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks.